# Ошибка 1 в Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

Есть 2 цели в makefile:

```
test: s21_matrix.a
    gcc $(CFLAGS) test.c s21_matrix.a -L. $(LFLAGS) -o test
    -./test > test.log
    bash test_log.sh

leaks: s21_matrix.a
    gcc $(CFLAGS) test.c s21_matrix.a -L. $(LFLAGS) -o test
    CK_FORK=no $(LEAK) ./test > leak.log
    bash test_leak.sh
```

Первая выполняется нормально. Вторая вроде как отрабатывает среднюю строку, все записывает в leak.log, но после записи выдает `make: *** [leaks] Error 1` ну и последующий скрипт не запускается. В чём может быть косяк?

Comment: Значения переменных покажите

Comment: во всех зависимостях отсутствует `test.c` => `test: test.c s21_matrix.a`

Comment: Ну в первом правиле вы игнорируете ошибки запуска `./test`, а во втором нет. Вангую что `./test` завершается с ошибкой.